# __getitem__ invocation in for loop

Tags: python

I am learning Python I don't get one thing. Consider this code:

```
class Stack:
   def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

   def push(self, item):
       self.items.append(item)

   def pop(self):
       return self.items.pop()

   def __getitem__(self,index):
       print "index",index
       return self.items[index]

   def __len__(self):
       return len(self.items)


stack = Stack()
stack.push(2)
stack.push(1)
stack.push(0)

for item in stack:
    print item
```

and the output

```
index 0
2
index 1
1
index 2
0
index 3
```

Why is **getitem** called four times?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `for` loop doesn't know how to iterate over your object specifically because you have not implemented `__iter__()`, so it uses the default iterator. This starts at index 0 and goes until it gets an `IndexError` by asking for index 3. See http://effbot.org/zone/python-for-statement.htm.

Your implementation would be a lot simpler if you derived from `list`, by the way. You wouldn't need `__init__()`, `pop()`, or `__getitem__()`, and `push` could be just another name for `append`. Also, since `list` has a perfectly good `__iter()__` method, `for` will know how to iterate it without going past the end of the list.

```
class Stack(list):
    push = list.append
```

Comment: actually my original code had it, see the update. It is the same.

Comment: Yes, I'm wrong in the details. Turns out to be `__iter__()` not `__len__()`. Fixing that up now.

Comment: Excellent. BTW any better way to implement this than   def  _iter__(self):
       for i in self.items:
           yield i