# Torch Dataset Looping too far

Tags: python, pytorch

Why does this dataset try to iterate past the final element

```
from torch.utils.data.dataset import Dataset
class DumbDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dct):
        self.dct = dct
        self.mapping = dict(enumerate(dct))
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.dct[self.mapping[index]]

    def __len__(self):
        print('called')
        return len(self.dct)

ds = DumbDataset({'a': 'aword', 'b': 'another_words'})

for k in ds: print(k)
```

This raises KeyError: 2, which I don't understand since length of the object is 2. Shouldn't the iterator get StopIteration once it is exhausted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why your code raises `KeyError` is that `Dataset` [does not implement](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/4292d13240e23a4a343b4ccb153214ab11c8d255/torch/utils/data/dataset.py#L8) `__iter__()` and thus when used in a for-loop Python falls back to starting at index `0` and calling `__getitem__` until `IndexError` is raised, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439482/getitem-invocation-in-for-loop). You can modify `DumbDataset` to work like this by having it raise an `IndexError` when the index is out of bounds

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    if index >= len(self): raise IndexError
    return self.dct[self.mapping[index]]
```

and then your loop

```
for k in ds:
    print(k)
```

will work as you expected. On the other hand, the typical template for torch datasets is that you can either loop through them with indexing

```
for i in range(len(ds)):
    k = ds[k]
    print(k)
```

or that you wrap them in a `DataLoader` which returns elements in batches

```
generator = DataLoader(ds)
for k in generator:
    print(k)
```